# CSV parsed with pandas and casted to dict results in KeyError in last row only

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file that I’m parsing with the help of pandas and casting to a dict like so: `contacts = read_csv(file_handle).to_dict()`. So `contacts` is now a dict, and contains the following keys:

```
(Pdb) contacts.keys()
['FirstName', 'Title', 'LastName', 'EmailAddress']
```

There’s a few thousand rows, and I need to access them in some way so I tried many, many different for loops, one is:

```
for i, name in enumerate(contacts['FirstName'].values()):
    parsed_contacts.append(dict(
        first_name=name,
        last_name=...
    ))
```

(the above example has been shortened for display purposes)
Now this works correctly, until the very last row, on which it throws a KeyError on FirstName:

```
File "/app/importer/contacts.py", line 290, in parse_contacts
    for i, name in enumerate(contacts['FirstName'].values()):
KeyError: 'FirstName'
```

this makes no sense to me: it literally works for 4041 rows and fails at row 4042 with a KeyError

Same thing if I access it in some other way:

```
for i in range(len(contacts['FirstName'].values())):
    parsed_contacts.append(dict(
        first_name=contacts['FirstName'][i],
```

Not sure what’s going on there, it’s driving me crazy because these work if I run them interactively in pdb:

```
(Pdb) for i, name in enumerate(contacts['FirstName'].values()): print             
name
John
Juliette
...
nan
Jose
Jesús
Frances
(Pdb) for i in range(len(contacts['FirstName'].values())): print i
0
...
4040
4041
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Why are you accessing the values like this?

Comment: Also, why are you converting it to a dict after you convert it to a dataframe? Why not just use csv DictReader if you don't care about pandas?

Comment: Pandas was already available there so it felt like the most straightforward choice, but you're right I'll give DictReader a shot.

Comment: DictReader was way better suited for my use case, if your comment @CoryMadden was an answer instead of a comment I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually happens when there is a new line at the end of the csv file. So when the csv reader reads the file, it basically picks it up as an empty record with no keys. Hence, a key error is raised. One work around is that you can use [dict.get() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to ensure that an error is not raised. You can look for [more examples here] and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)[3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm). Also double check if there is no extra line at the end of the csv file.

Comment: Oh I tried `contacts.get('FirstName', [])` but the outcome was that _none_ of the rows got parsed instead.

Comment: There seemed to be an extra line at the end of the CSV file, removing it solved the issue. However I moved over to using csv.DictReader instead of pandas.